# Showing Facebook User name instead of user token using Facebook Login and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-server

In my app users are able to log in/ sign up by creating a username and password or by logging in with Facebook. Parse stores their username and password. It does the same for Facebook, but it stores the users token (I think) instead of the username. I then display the users names in a table view, but the Facebook users show up as a user token like : Afjkd233edJ instead of their user name. I am using Facebook graph api also, it stores the name under name in my class User. I am not able however to get that name to post instead of the token thing. Here is the code I am using in my View controller which handles login and sign up and then bellow that is my table view controller which display the users and who they are following or not following. EDIT: I forgot to to mention that I am using parse server and have migrated it over to Heroku and am using the mongoldb dyno.

## VIEWCONTROLLER

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var signupActive = true

@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var signupButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var registeredText: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!


var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}










@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

    if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

        displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password")

    } else {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        var errorMessage = "Please try again later"

        if signupActive == true {

            let user = PFUser()
            user.username = username.text
            user.password = password.text



            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                if error == nil {

                    // Signup successful

                    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

                    var initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarControllerID") as! UIViewController
                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


                } else {

                    if let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                        errorMessage = errorString

                    }

                    self.displayAlert("Failed SignUp", message: errorMessage)

                }

            })

        } else {

            PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text!, password: password.text!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                if user != nil {

                    // Logged In!

                    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

                    var initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarControllerID") as! UIViewController
                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


                } else {

                    if let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                        errorMessage = errorString

                    }

                    self.displayAlert("Failed Login", message: errorMessage)

                }

            })

        }

    }






}

@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject) {


    if signupActive == true {

        signupButton.setTitle("Log In", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        registeredText.text = "Not registered?"

        loginButton.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        signupActive = false

    } else {

        signupButton.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        registeredText.text = "Already registered?"

        loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        signupActive = true

    }

}


@IBAction func faceBookLogIn(sender: AnyObject) {



    let permissions = ["public_profile"]






    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: {

        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {

            print(error)

        } else {





            let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender"])
            graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler( {

                (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {

                    print(error)

                } else if let result = result {


                    PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]!

                    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()

                    let userId = result["id"]! as! String



                }

            })







            if let user = user {

                //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

                var initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarControllerID") as! UIViewController
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()



            }



        }



    })



}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.





}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


    if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate

        var initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarControllerID") as! UIViewController
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 }
```

## TABELVIEW

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var usernames = [""]
var userids = [""]
var isFollowing = ["":false]

var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

func refresh() {

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {

            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.userids.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    if user.objectId! != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                        self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                        self.userids.append(user.objectId!)

                        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers")

                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)

                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                            if let objects = objects {

                                if objects.count > 0 {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                                } else {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false

                                }
                            }

                            if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {

                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                                self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                            }


                        })



                    }
                }

            }



        }



    })





}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()

    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

    refresh()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return usernames.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

    let followedObjectId = userids[indexPath.row]

    if isFollowing[followedObjectId] == true {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    }


    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    let followedObjectId = userids[indexPath.row]

    if isFollowing[followedObjectId] == false {

        isFollowing[followedObjectId] = true

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

        var following = PFObject(className: "followers")
        following["following"] = userids[indexPath.row]
        following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId

        following.saveInBackground()

    } else {

        isFollowing[followedObjectId] = false

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers")

        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: userids[indexPath.row])

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    object.deleteInBackground()

                }
            }


        })



    }

}
}
```

Comment: Parse.com development stopped. It will be closed as a service till the January 2017. You should use **alternative service**. Please, read [this official Parse announcement](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/) and also [regarding the migration](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-parse-server-and-the-database-migration-tool/)

Comment: Also you could try [Backendless service](https://backendless.com)
using their [Parse migration Guide](https://backendless.com/parse-to-backendless-migration-guide/)

Comment: I am using parse server on Heroku I forgot to mention this sorry.